# Proving logarithm of CDF of bivariate normal is concave in $\rho$ (the correlation).

Tags: gaussian-integral, bivariate-distributions, distribution-tails

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables and let the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ be bivariate normal with mean $[0,0]$ and covariance $\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & \rho \\
    \rho      & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$. And let $\Phi_2$ be the CDF of $(X,Y)$. Then, can we prove (or disprove) that $\log{\Phi_2(a,b,\rho)}$ is concave in $\rho$? where $a,b$ are constants and  $\log{\Phi_2(a,b,\rho)} = \mathbb{P}(X \leq a, Y \leq b; \rho)$

Here are the first and second derivatives of $\log{\Phi_2(a,b,\rho)}$. Let $f(\sigma) = \log{\Phi_2(a, b; \sigma)}$. Then :
\begin{equation}
f'(\sigma) = \frac{\phi_2(a,b;\sigma)}{\Phi_2(a,b;\sigma)},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f''(\sigma) = \frac{\phi_2(a,b;\sigma)}{\Phi_2(a,b;\sigma)}\left[\frac{\sigma(1 - c)}{1 - \sigma^2} + \frac{ab}{1 - \sigma^2} - \frac{\phi_2(a,b;\sigma)}{\Phi_2(a,b;\sigma)}\right],
\end{equation}
where $c = \frac{a^2 + b^2 - 2\sigma ab}{1 - \sigma^2}$ and $\phi_2$ is the PDF of $(X,Y)$.